# Dispatching action once reender automaticaly component once doesn't

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I use react, redux, and redux-thunk middlewere.

My code looks like :

```
  function thunkFunction(){
  return(dispatch) => { 
    dispatch(toggleSmth(false));
    dispatch(toggle2Smth(false));

    SomeService.getSmth()
    .then(response => {

      dispatch(oneMoreAction);
      dispatch(one2MoreAction);

    }
  }
}
```

And now I dispatch that whole thunk action after componenDidMount() in some component.

It works like that :

1. dispatch(toggleSmth(false));
2. dispatch(toggle2Smth(false));
3. Promise to callback queue (not doing .then elements)
4. } going to the close curly bracket
5. **Component reender**
6. going to .then(
7. dispatching(oneMoreAction)
8. **Automatically component reender** (WHY!?)
9. back to the second dispatch -> dispatching(one2MoreAction)
10. Another **automatically component reender** (WHY!?)

The question is :

Why once the dispatch wait for whole stack to clear. And in Promise after dispatch component is automatically reendered and after that it backs to the next Promise function element ?

In addition when I put dispatch(toggleSmth(false)) inside of promise like that :

```
function thunkFunction(){=
  return(dispatch) => { 
    SomeService.getSmth()
    .then(response => {

      dispatch(toggleSmth(false));
      dispatch(toggle2Smth(false));
      dispatch(oneMoreAction);
      dispatch(one2MoreAction);

    }
  }
}
```

The `dispatch(toggleSmth(false))` and `dispatch(toggle2Smth(false))` automatically reender component. (Not wait for clear the callback stack '}'). And after reender goes next -> to first `dispatch(oneMoreAction);`

Why once dispatching causing automatically reender and once you have to wait for execution of element inside of function ?

Comment: But once it works like you said and once doesn't

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a little misunderstanding about 2 things:

- The react component life cycle
- The way thunk actually works.

What is going on, at the most basic level, is you are calling a thunk action (a proimise) which calls dispatch 4 times in total. Every time you call an action that modifies the state, the components touched by that state (via `mapStateToProps`) will re-render.

When you put all of the dispatch functions under 1 async call (i.e nested once) (`SomeService.getSmth().then(() => {...});)` in this case) it causes those to fire synchronously relative to each other... the component still re-renders though because it is touched by a state that is being modified.

In the first case, the 2 dispatch's are called synchronously relative to each other, **then** the service call happens along with the other two dispatches *only after the service call finishes*

Comment: You explained when and how it behaves. My question was why it behaves like that?